# Xcode 7 beta 6 cannot create new project

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

Xcode crash when creating a new project, I have tried the following solutions

- Reset Xcode preferences with `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`
- Restart Mac OS X
- Update Mac OS X to 10.11 Beta (15A216g)

The issue still exist while Xcode beta 5 works fine.

Comment: whats logged to the OS X console by xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From known issues section of [this document](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_6/Xcode_7_beta_6_Release_Notes.pdf):

> Creating new projects on OS X El Capitan requires developer beta 7 or later. (22263243)

I recommend you to update to the latest beta if possible, this will definitely solve the issue. But you can also create project with beta 5, then edit it using beta 6

Comment: I am using OS X El Capitan developer beta 6. I will give a try on beta 7 today.

Comment: Update to OS X El Capitan developer beta 7 fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 7 is currently in beta, there's a good chance of coming across random issues like this.

Do you necessarily need to use Xcode 7 beta 6?

If not, it is probably not worth trying to fix yourself. If you need to create a new project, try creating it with Xcode 7 beta 5 (since you mentioned it works), and then open the newly created project in Xcode 7 beta 6.